# fixed navigation after full screen header

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullscreen

I'm having a full screen header on a single-page website. After the hero element, there is my navigation element, which should be fixed after scrolling past the full screen height. Here's what I have by now.

HTML:

```
<div id="hero">
    <div class="welcome">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/>
    </div>
    <a href="http://localhost/elephant/#inner-header"><img class="arrow" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/arrow.png" alt="Weiter"/></a>
</div>

<nav class="nav"> (...) </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#hero {
    background-image:url(../images/hero.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    position:relative;
    height:100vh;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
/* $(".navbar-fixed-top").css({"top":$("#hero").height()});

    $(window).resize(function (e) {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").css({"top":$("#hero").height()});
    }); */

$(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
    console.log('scroll top : ' + $(window).scrollTop());
        if($(window).scrollTop()>=$("#hero").height())
        {
             $(".nav").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
        }

        if($(window).scrollTop()<$("#hero").height())
        {
             $(".nav").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
        }
    });
});
```

Can you see where I have made a mistake?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Please provide a working example on JSFiddle or similar.

Comment: Is the class `navbar-fixed-top` getting applied to the div when you scroll past the `#hero`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your javascript is working fine. I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msechrest/1gL1sxbe/) that seems to work just fine. All i added was some css like so:

```
.nav.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Take a look at the fiddle and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get the navigation element to stay fixed at the top of the screen as you scroll down. I think the first thing to try is 'position:sticky' on the nav element and see if that works?

Comment: `position:sticky` has almost no browser support except for FF & Safari.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I need to add position: fixed; top:0; somewhere... But where?